# GraphicsPath.IsVisible() does not return if the point is inside the polygon correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I add a polygon to the `GraphicsPath` and try to check if the rectangle is positioned inside of it. When rectangle is completely outside the polygon code responds correctly. However, when inside the polygon its return value is unpredictable.
For now I only check top-left corner of the rectangle.

```cs
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g = e.Graphics;
    rect = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(30,30));
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, rect);
    Point[] points = new Point[]
    {
        new Point(0, 0),
        new Point(50, 0),
        new Point(50, 50),
        new Point(0, 50),
    };
    graphicsPath.AddPolygon(points);
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, points);
    if ((graphicsPath.IsVisible(rect.Location)))
    {
        this.Text = "Inside " + rect.Location.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Text = "not inside " + rect.Location.ToString();
    }
}
```

I also have some code which is used to move the rectangle using MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseMove events.

The results I receive are:
[image: Inside {X=10; Y=10}]

But after repainting the form (even just minimizing window) those same coordinates are responding differently and the result is:
[image: not inside {X=10; Y=10}]

Comment: X positive direction is left to right.  Y positive direction is top to bottom (not bottom to top).

Comment: And this code is written with this in mind @jdweng.

Comment: @fuvaji Where is `graphicsPath` declared? Do you clear it between the paints?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks! I added graphicsPath.Reset() in the end of Paint function and now it works.

Comment: You shouldn't define the Polygon in the Paint event handler, nor call `.AddPolygon()` there. You have stored a GraphicsPath object, hence create a procedure that adds and  removes figures, or clears it, when needed. In the Paint handler, just draw the current GraphicsPath object. If you add a figure to it (using your procedure), just `Invalidate()` the canvas right after.